# Record Skype video?

Tags: software-rec, skype, video-capture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any free Skype Video Recorder?](https://superuser.com/questions/63401/any-free-skype-video-recorder)

How can I record Skype video? Is there any thing like call graph (it is for audio). Is there anything for video?

Comment: Looks like a dupe then: http://superuser.com/questions/63401/any-free-skype-video-recorder

Comment: Sorry its my mistake ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not free, but you can record video in Skype using [Vodburner](http://www.vodburner.com/).

If you want to know more about it, there's a [review by TechCrunch](http://www.techcrunch.com/2009/10/29/vodburner-brings-high-quality-video-recording-and-editing-to-skype/) on it.

Check out this related question, [Any free Skype Video Recorder?](https://superuser.com/questions/63401/any-free-skype-video-recorder)